# ComboBox.Items.IndexOf returns -1

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox, indexof, selectedindex

I have a `ComboBox` which is populated on Page Load event. Just after populating the `ComboBox` I call another method which returns a value that I want to make the default value of the `ComboBox` when `Page loads`. How can I change the `selectedIndex` to a value that is returned when I call another method?

XAML for `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox Name="cboProductType" DisplayMemberPath="ProductTypeName" SelectedValuePath="ProductTypeID" SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Page Load event:

```
void OnProductDetailLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   GetServiceReference.Service1Client service = new GetServiceReference.Service1Client();
   service.GetProductDetailsCompleted += service_GetProductDetailsCompleted;
   service.GetProductTypeCompleted += service_GetProductTypeCompleted;
   service.GetProductTypeAsync();
   service.GetProductDetailsAsync(ProductId);
}
```

Populating ComboBox when Page Loads:

```
void service_GetProductTypeCompleted(object sender, GetProductTypeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    cboProductType.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}
```

Calling the other method which returns a particular `ProductTypeName`. I tried to get the index of that particular `ProductTypeName` but returns `-1` always.

```
void service_GetProductDetailsCompleted(object sender, GetServiceReference.GetProductDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Result.Count != 0)
   {
      p.ProductID = e.Result[0].ProductID;
     int index = cboProductType.Items.IndexOf(e.Result[0].ProductTypeName);
    cboProductType.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Also is this a right approach for setting the `SelectedIndex` property?
Say I have following items loaded in `ComboBox` in following Index order:

```
Index    DisplayMemberName(ProductTypeName)

   0           Color
   1           Size
   2           Variant
   3           N-size
```

and `e.Result[0].ProductTypeName` contains `Variant` so I now want `SelectedIndex = 2` of ComboBox

I hope my question is clear

Comment: `ComboBox.Items.IndexOf()` will return `-1` only when the particular item is not in the collection. so debug your program and check the value of `e.Result[0].ProductTypeName

Comment: I did. The value is present in my `combobox`. Is there any other approach I can use to set the Index?

Comment: @un-lucky I have a simple requirement. Can you tell me how I can achieve it? The `SelectedIndex` is at 0 right now. I want to change the `SelectedIndex`

Comment: When you are binding to data `..Itemsource = ...`, SelectedIndex is not valid. I believe you need the `SelectedValue` and you need to set it to the `ProductTypeID` you want selected. It might be just `Value`

Comment: @Steve can you answer my post instead of the comment so I can mark it? You made my day! I was getting crazy after this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectedIndex` is only valid when you manually fill a combobox. If you are using the `ItemsSource` to fill the items in a combobox, you must define a `SelectedValuePath` which will then allows you to use the `SelectedItem` property to SET/GET the selected item. When using binding to a `DataContext` to bind the controls, the `SelectedValuePath` should be the property that links the Parent/Child together.